# How to load an image onto the page with react from dynamic data?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, loader

I want to display an image on my react app page

```
import egypt from '../images/egypt.svg'

<div>
   <img src={egypt}/>
</div>
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Also I want to load it in from an object like this:

```
options: [{
       optionOne: {
         answer: 'bolivia',
         image: './images/egypt.svg'
       }
     }]
```

how can I display it on screen?

my error is saying I need an appropriate loader. I tried to use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-webpack-loader

but it says: `Can't resolve 'file-loader'`

```
  {
    test: /\.svg$/i,
    loaders: [
        'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
        'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to import the image file? Why don't you just use a regular `src` attribute for the image tag, with a URL to the image file? There's nothing special that you need to do

Comment: @inostia, If you did use react with webpack you would know that you need to import or require images before providing it as a source

Comment: Did you install file-loader?

Answer (score 0):

If

```
import egypt from '../images/egypt.svg'

<div>
   <img src={egypt}/>
</div>
```

works in your code and you have configured the webpack properly, you would be able to dynamically display the image in React by requiring them with the help of template literals like

```
<img src={require(`${obj.optionOne.img}`)}
```

Also make sure you install `url loader` with command

```
npm install -s url-loader
```

You need to configure your `webpack` with `url-loader` as

```
 {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
        use:['url-loader']
    }
```

Comment: obj.optionOne.img is string itself. Why we need template literals?

Comment: because directly writing require(obj.optionOne.img) somehow doesn't resolve it

Comment: Ya directly passing string variable to require does not resolve it. It is strange to see how template literals does the trick.