# Best practice to use image in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

Just curious how do you use picture in react? I use webpack so I assume it would be like this

```
import Picture from '../assets/images/mypic.jpeg'

render(){
   <div>
      <Picture />
   </div>
}
```

but isn't that tedious to import every single images u want to use?

Comment: Importing the pictures in your code makes it easy for the webpack to package it to the browser. See the graphic on https://webpack.github.io/. Do you not want to include the pictures in the React because of laziness or is it because you want it dynamically load?

Generally, for any other questions on standards and best practices I have, I usually go to https://vasanthk.gitbooks.io/react-bits/.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287748/how-to-load-an-image-onto-the-page-with-react-from-dynamic-data/45287962#45287962

Answer (score 3):

You use `img` tags just like in HTML:

```
import myPicture from '../assets/images/mypic.jpeg'


render() {
  <div>
    <img src={myPicture} alt="My Picture" />
  </div>
}
```

Comment: in this case, yes.

Comment: what is the name of the loader?

Answer (score 0):

Stole function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53762640/how-to-import-all-images-from-a-folder-in-reactjs)

Have not tested it myself, but it sounds similar to what you're looking for.

```
const importAll = (r) => r.keys().map(r);

const images = importAll(require.context('../assets/images/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));


render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {images.map((pic, i) =>
        <img src={pic} alt={`picture-${i}`} />
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```