# How to import all images from a folder in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to import all images from a folder and want to use as needed.
But can't do it by following methods.
What I am doing?
this:

```
import * as imageSrc from '../img';
let imageUrl = [];
    imageSrc.map(
    imageUrl.push(img) 
    ))
```

I am getting this error in console.log

```
index.js:1452 ./src/components/Main.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '../img' in 'G:\Projects\Personal\Portfolios\Portfolio_Main\React_portfolio\portfolio\src\components'
```

Folder Structure:

```
src>
  components>
    Main.jsx
  img>
    [all image files]
```

Comment: are you using webpack to build the code?

Comment: yes, I am using webpack by default.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is not possible in plain javascript because import/export are determined statically.

If you are using webpack, have a look at require.context . You should be able to do the following:

```js
function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}

const images = importAll(require.context('./', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
```

ref: https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context

Comment: How to use webpack in react?

Comment: Did you have generated your app via create-react-app CLI ?

Comment: yes,
Webpack is default. but how to load images to array after importing them?

Comment: In the snippet 'images' variable contains an array of images path resolved by webpack

Comment: it does't return any array. it returns object with empty array!

Comment: If array is empty parameters are wrong, what's your first parameters of require.context() ? where is the folder containing the images ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53777194/webpack-dynamic-import-method-returns-empty-array-instead-of-files-in-reactjs-h

Comment: @Chetankumar yes is the same as the WebPack doc, I use it in some project so I can confirm it works if configuration is fine

Comment: I have linked the path of question. Can you please review that?

Comment: Done, try that, it seems the folder in the first parameter is wrong, try to read documentation linked here, commented examples are provided