# Webpack dynamic import method returns empty array instead of files in reactjs, How to solve?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

How to import and use images in Reactjs?
I have imported all images from a folder but it does't return array with links.
check this.

```
    function importAll(r) {
    return r.keys().map(r);
  }
    const images = importAll(require.context('./', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
    console.log(images);
```

Check this screenshot of console:

[image]

Please help me in this!

Folder structure:

```
--src>
  --components>
      Projects.jsx
  --img>
       images
```

I am trying to import it in Projects component.
but, How to do this?

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';

function importAll(r) {
    return r.keys().map(r);
}

const images = importAll(require.context('./', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
console.log(images);
```

Please help in load the all images and use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct require for you would be:

```
importAll(require.context('./img', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
```

From docs:

```js
require.context('./test', false, /\.test\.js$/);
// a context with files from the test directory that can be required with a request endings with `.test.js`.


require.context('../', true, /\.stories\.js$/);
// a context with all files in the parent folder and descending folders ending with `.stories.js`.
```

Comment: Oh, i had not seen the problem with path. I got it now.
Also there should be two dot : importAll(require.context('../img', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)); 
It's working now. Thanks a lot