# How to display every image inside an image folder in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, jsx

I have an image folder in my `create-react-app` project with a bunch of images. I want to display every single image in the components.

```
├── Components
│   ├── Icons
│   │   ├── Icon.jsx (I want to display every single icon)
│  
│  
├── Images
│   ├── Icons
│   │   ├── ... (over 100 SVG icons)
```

In my .jsx file, I want to loop over every image/icon and display it.

**Icons.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Icons from '../../Images/Icons';


class Icons extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      //Loop over every icon and display it
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are the images named in a particular order or have a pattern associated with them?

Comment: @Richard what have you tried so far?

Comment: @SatejS yeah they have a specific pattern to them. They have naming conventions such as "outline", "sizes", etc

Comment: Assuming there are some very strict naming conventions and formats such as "outline-250","outline-300", "sizes-200", your rendering loop could render with increments in the value of the digit.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of  = > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53762640/how-to-import-all-images-from-a-folder-in-reactjs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same scenario where I have to pick `images` or `SVG`s from the folder and display it. Below is the process I followed :

**Folder structure**

```
  -public
   -src
     |-component
     |-images
        |-1.png
        |-2.png
        |-3.png
        .
        .
        |-some x number.png
```

In `component` where ever you want to consume the `image` there, you have to do this:

```
export default App;
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
var listOfImages =[];

class App extends React.Component{
    importAll(r) {
        return r.keys().map(r);
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        listOfImages = this.importAll(require.context('./images/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
    }
    render(){
        return(
          <div>
              {
                    listOfImages.map(
                      (image, index) =>    <img key={index} src={image} alt="info"></img>
                    )
              }
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

It worked for me; Give it a try.

Comment: if my answer is full fills your requirement please mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/blob/master/packages/react-icons/scripts/build.js. The author takes many folders of svg's and turns them into usable components in react.  It's a repeatable workflow that should work for your svg icon pack as well if you retrofit that script into your app.

In some ways for webpack, you'd need something like an `index.js` file in that `'../../Images/Icons'` folder that exports all the icons for easy import elsewhere.

You can do some quick and dirty bash tricks (like `lsa`) and with your editor (multi-cursor/find-and-replace) to get the filenames and make that index.js file once.  Then adding to it will not take much effort. But it's probably better to use a script that can generate an "exports file" on demand from a folder of svgs.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably seen this one if you've looked around

```
export default function getImagePaths(directory) {
  let images = [];
  directory.keys().map((item, index) => images.push(item.replace("./", "")));
  return images;
}
```

This function returns an array of paths to each photo in the desired directory. Using this I created an **index.js** file in a folder called **gallery**

```
const directory = require.context("../", false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/);
let imagePaths = getImagePaths(directory);

let images = [];
imagePaths.map((path) => images.push(require("../" + path)));

export default images
```

This index file uses the string array returned from getImagePaths and creates its own array with `imagePaths.map((path) => images.push(require("../"+path)));`
This array is then exported from **index.js** and used in the page.

Here is a snippet of it in use.

```
import images from "../assets/images/gallery";
import "../assets/css/gallery.css";

const Gallery = () => {
  return (
    <div id="gallery-container">
      {images.map((img, index) => (
        <div>
          <img key={index} src={img} alt={img} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```