# get asset images dynamically in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My assets

```
/public
  /flags
    flags_a.png
    flags_ramdom_name.png
    flags_ramdon_name2.png
    ...
```

I want to import all of them dynamically.
Such like this...

```js
const allFlags = getImages('/public/flags'); // ['flags_a.png', 'flag_random_name.png', ...]

return (
  <div>
    {allFlags.map((src)=> <img src={src} />);
  </div>
);
```

How can I achieve it in React.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think glob module can help you this will recursively get you all file names with .png

```
var glob = require("glob")

glob("/public/flags/*.png", options, function (er, files) {
console.log(files)
// files is an array of filenames.

})
```

install glob with npm [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob)

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56347783/how-to-display-every-image-inside-an-image-folder-in-react)