# How to use all images from a folder in react js

Tags: reactjs

In my react project how can I use all the images from a folder?

I tried this :

```
importAll(r) {

    return r.keys().map(r);
  }
  userPath="../css/pics/"+this.props.user+"/";

  images = this.importAll(require.context("../css/pics/"+this.props.user, false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
```

But this is giving `TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function`.

I know this question is already asked here : [How to import all images from a folder in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53762640/how-to-import-all-images-from-a-folder-in-reactjs) But it didn't helped me.

Now how can I solve this?

Comment: are you using webpack? this will only work with webpack as the answer mentions. it should be already configured if you're using create-react-app to bootstrap your project

Comment: Yes.I've created app using create-react-app only

Comment: @VasuCh You can't actually do that, unfortunately, Webpack doesn't "yet" support [dynamic expressions in import](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import), it need to be hard-coded like: `../css/pics/john`

Comment: But I need to give it dynamically.Is there any other alternatives for that?