# How to iterate through public/assets/images so i can get all images filename in an array?

Tags: reactjs

I have images in public/assets/images. There's 100 images with different file extension (png, jpg, webp, etc). I'm trying to make a list of images and those images are taken from public/assets/images. How to iterate through public/assets/images so i can get all images filename in an array?. And here's how my code look like.

```
const ImageList = () => {
  const filenames = [an array consist of image filename in public/assets/images]
  return (
    <ul>
      {
        filenames.map(filename => {
          return <li>
            <img src={filename} alt={filename} />
          </li>
        })
      }
    </ul>
  )
}

export default ImageList
```

Here's my project structure

```
public
-assets
--images
--- image1.jpg
--- image2.png
--- image3.webp
--- ...
src
-components
--ImageList.js
--...
App.js
```

Comment: What is your project structure look like?

Comment: Wait, i'll edit and show my project structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53762640/how-to-import-all-images-from-a-folder-in-reactjs)! Change './' to your image directory (try to find it when you access the web because it is managed by webpack).

```
function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}

const ImageList = () => {
  const filenames = importAll(require.context('./', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
  return (
    <ul>
      {
        filenames.map(filename => {
          return <li>
            <img src={filename} alt={filename} />
          </li>
        })
      }
    </ul>
  )
}

export default ImageList
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `public` in the path because the index.html is the same location with `assets`

```
const filenames = ["./assets/images/image1.jpg"]
```

Comment: I want to get all filename in public/assets/images not just one and i don't want to manually create the array.